# Copying jsFiddle code with configurations to dashboard?

Tags: jsfiddle

Is there any way on jsFiddle so that i can copy other users public jsFiddle code to my dashboard? I can do it by manually copying the code and configurations but i couldn't find any option for this on jsfiddle.net.

 **edit**

tried to fork but it doesn't bring code in my dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to signin with your jsFiddle account and then Fork the fiddle to bring it into your dashboard. Hope this helps...

Comment: i have tried to fork with several jsFiddle codes but they are not appearing on my dashboard any idea?